# A question on differentiation

Tags: derivatives

Let a function $y(x) = \tan^{-1}(x)$.  Now let $n = 4p + 3$ and differentiate $y$ $n$ times with respect to $x$ at $x = 0$. So it generalizes to $-(n-1)!$. Now, is there any method without repeatedly differentiating the function?

Comment: What is the significance of $n$ being $4p+3$?

Comment: Also, a method for doing *what*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$ \tan ^{-1} x = x-\frac {x^3}{3} +\frac {x^5}{5} -\frac {x^7}{7}+..$$

When you take derivatives and evaluate at $x=0$ you see that factorials appear with a regular pattern.

$$ y=  x-\frac {x^3}{3} +\frac {x^5}{5} -\frac {x^7}{7}+..$$
$$ y'= 1-x^2 + x^4 - x^6+....$$ 
$$ y'' = -2x+4x^3-6x^5+.....$$

$$ y''' = -2+ 12x^2 - 30x^4 + ....$$

Answer (score 0):

We can find the Taylor series of $y(x)$ centered at $x=0$ by considering its derivative. $$y'(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j x^{2j}$$
Integrating both sides and putting $y(0)=0$ gives $$y(x)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j}{2j+1}x^{2j+1}$$
Now compare this to the formula for Taylor series $$y(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{y^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$$